# Two very similar functions involving sin() exhibit vastly different performance -- why?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, floating-point, x86

Consider the following two programs that perform the same computations in two different ways:

```
// v1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
   int i, j;
   int nbr_values = 8192;
   int n_iter = 100000;
   float x;
   for (j = 0; j < nbr_values; j++) {
      x = 1;
      for (i = 0; i < n_iter; i++)
         x = sin(x);
   }
   printf("%f\n", x);
   return 0;
}
```

and

```
// v2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
   int i, j;
   int nbr_values = 8192;
   int n_iter = 100000;
   float x[nbr_values];
   for (i = 0; i < nbr_values; ++i) {
      x[i] = 1;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < n_iter; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < nbr_values; ++j) {
         x[j] = sin(x[j]);
      }
   }
   printf("%f\n", x[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile them using gcc 4.7.2 with `-O3 -ffast-math` and run on a Sandy Bridge box, the second program is twice as fast as the first one.

Why is that?

One suspect is the data dependency between successive iterations of the `i` loop in `v1`. However, I don't quite see what the full explanation might be.

(Question inspired by [Why is my python/numpy example faster than pure C implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466950/why-is-my-python-numpy-example-faster-than-pure-c-implementation))

**EDIT:**

Here is the generated assembly for `v1`:

```
        movl    $8192, %ebp
        pushq   %rbx
LCFI1:
        subq    $8, %rsp
LCFI2:
        .align 4
L2:
        movl    $100000, %ebx
        movss   LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        jmp     L5
        .align 4
L3:
        call    _sinf
L5:
        subl    $1, %ebx
        jne     L3
        subl    $1, %ebp
        .p2align 4,,2
        jne     L2
```

and for `v2`:

```
        movl    $100000, %r14d
        .align 4
L8:
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
        .align 4
L9:
        movss   (%r12,%rbx), %xmm0
        call    _sinf
        movss   %xmm0, (%r12,%rbx)
        addq    $4, %rbx
        cmpq    $32768, %rbx
        jne     L9
        subl    $1, %r14d
        jne     L8
```

Comment: Try using `double` instead of `float`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `double` makes no difference.

Comment: in the second code, could it be because all x[j] = sin(x[j]) for all j >=1 will be identical to x[0] after the initial sin-calc?, thereby the entire inner loop can be thrown out and replaced with a single sin-calc and a fill? (just guessing here). The first loop calcs a value-dependent sin with each inner-loop iteration, the second snippet has no such restriction.

Comment: @NPE I reckon that the data dependency may be the full explanation. What makes you think there's another reason? Because of the data 'independency' in the second version, the processor can preload the next value for computation while computing the previous one, etc. I'm no expert with CPU architectures, but since today's processor pipelines are quite long, I would consider it plausible that this actually accounts for that performance difference.

Comment: @NPE I believe Stephen Canon himself *is* the expert on x86 architecture.

Comment: Seriously, have you looked at his [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/142434/stephen-canon)?  40k+ reputation just answering questions about Assembly, Math, Floating point, C etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ignore the loop structure all together, and only think about the sequence of calls to `sin`.  `v1` does the following:

```
x <-- sin(x)
x <-- sin(x)
x <-- sin(x)
...
```

that is, each computation of `sin( )` cannot begin until the result of the previous call is available; it must wait for the entirety of the previous computation.  This means that for N calls to `sin`, the total time required is 819200000 times the latency of a single `sin` evaluation.

In `v2`, by contrast, you do the following:

```
x[0] <-- sin(x[0])
x[1] <-- sin(x[1])
x[2] <-- sin(x[2])
...
```

notice that each call to `sin` does not depend on the previous call.  Effectively, the calls to `sin` are all independent, and the processor can begin on each as soon as the necessary register and ALU resources are available (without waiting for the previous computation to be completed).  Thus, the time required is a function of the *throughput* of the sin function, not the latency, and so `v2` can finish in significantly less time.

---

I should also note that DeadMG is right that `v1` and `v2` are formally equivalent, and in a perfect world the compiler would optimize both of them into a single chain of 100000 `sin` evaluations (or simply evaluate the result at compile time).  Sadly, we live in an imperfect world.

Comment: v1 doesn't have any data dependencies- each variable used in the loop is reset each iteration.

Comment: @DeadMG: of course it does.  The value of `x` is a loop-carried dependency in v1.

Comment: @StephenCanon: No, it isn't. The loop sets `x` right back to `1` every time in the body, regardless of it's previous value. The compiler could ellide the outer loop completely. Similarly, in the second loop, only `x[0]` is accessed, so the compiler could ellide the computation of every other value.

Comment: @DeadMG: The *outer loop* resets `x`.  The inner loop does not.

Comment: I'm tempted to think that calls to `sin()` aren't easily overlapped due to the sheer cost of it. I dunno how large the re-order window of a modern x86 processor is. But I have a feeling that it is smaller than the # of instructions a call to `sin()` would take. Perhaps there's still room somewhere else that I overlooked?

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted you, but this is a *great* answer. The downvoters should be flogged.

Comment: Right. But equivalently, in v2, there is a data dependency in the outer loop, as `x[0]` is carried between iterations. There is no more data dependency in v1 than in v2.

Comment: @DeadMG: In the first example, the compiler should realize the outer loop can be completely elided. It doesn't though or the reported time would be much different.

Comment: @Mysticial: a typical `sinf` fits quite easily in the re-order window on a modern x86 machine.  Glancing at a couple of implementations we're talking about ~30-40 instructions.

Comment: Right. I'm not saying this isn't a compiler fail, because it clearly is, since they're completely equivalent in every respect. What I'm saying is that the first and second can both be optimized to the exact same result- and in fact, arguably, the first is a slightly more optimized version of the second.

Comment: @StephenCanon *Only* 30 instructions? Damn. Ok I believe you... +1

Comment: @DeadMG: And you're right, there is an equal amount of data dependency. The question is when it's needed. In the second one, the dependent value isn't needed until a whole ton of independent values are calculated. So if CPU resources can be consumed for the very next, completely independent calculation before another is finished, they can be. Not so in the first. Unless, of course, the compiler turns the loop inside out by itself (which it really ought to).

Comment: Right. So basically, the answer is "Because GCC wasn't intelligent enough to ellide the outer loop in the first version."

Comment: @StephenCanon: Is OSX Libm still using my `sin` implementation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: it is indeed.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the great explanation. Is there a one-line explanation why `gcc` isn't using the FPU instruction (`FSIN`), or is it worth posting a separate question about this?

Comment: @NPE: because FSIN is an order of magnitude slower than a good software implementation.

Comment: More importantly, FSIN gives the wrong result in general. It cannot do argument reduction.

Comment: @R..: yes, that too; I took "use FSIN" was shorthand for "use FPREM1 + FSIN" (which doesn't do a infinite-pi reduction, but at least does something).

Comment: I love beating the hardware with software. :-)

Comment: FPREM1 is also insufficient for trigonometric argument reduction.

Comment: FPREM1 is commonly used for trigonometric argument reduction.  You get garbage results, however.

Comment: Looking at glibc's implementation, it uses a sequence of add/sub/mul with SSE in 64-bit mode. And measuring the time it takes for 8192, the V2 loop is about 300K clock cycles on my machine, the V1 is around 400K clocks. I tried measuring the individual sin calculations, but the RDTSC is taking up too much of the total time to make it meaningful.

Comment: Please update the question or answer with any clarifying information, instead of filling up the comments with it. The comments are not meant for discussion.  If you want to have a discussion about these topics, you can always [take it to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) and link to that chat in these comments.

Comment: @George Stocker: Oh, come off it.  There's no extended discussion here (with the very borderline exception of the thread with DeadMG, but even there two rounds of back-and-forth is hardly "discussion"), just a bunch of clarifying questions and comments, and a few humorous asides.  Quoting meta: "Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not actually answer their parent questions. Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to and provide meta-information about posts."  This all fits that description.

Comment: @StephenCanon That's not where you put that onion ring: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164784/16587

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, it runs 100000 loops of sin, 8192 times.

In the second example, it runs 8192 loops of sin, 100000 times.

Other than that and storing the result differently, I don't see any difference.

However, what does make a difference is that the input is being changed for each loop in the second case. So I suspect what happens is that the sin value, at certain times in the loop, gets much easier to calculate. And that can make a big difference. Calculating sin is not entirely trivial, and it's a series calculation that loops until the exit condition is hit.

Comment: Why the downvote - I really don't like it when there is no comment for downvotes - I want to understand what is wrong...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's worth noting that both programs compute exactly the same `sin` values, just in a different order.