# Why is Numpy outperforming this cython routine by a factor 3

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have just started experimenting with cython and as a first exercise I created the following (re)implementation of a function computing the sin for each element of an array. So here's my sin.pyx

```
from numpy cimport ndarray, float64_t
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double sin(double x)

def sin_array(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
    cdef int n = len(arr)
    cdef ndarray h = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(n):
        h[i] = sin(arr[i])
    return h
```

I also created the following setup.py for this

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import numpy

ext = Extension("sin", sources=["sin.pyx"])

setup(ext_modules=[ext],
      cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

So this creates my *.so file. I import this into python and create 1000 random numbers, e.g.

```
import sin
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(1000)

%timeit sin.sin_array(x)
%timeit np.sin(x)
```

Numpy wins by a factor of 3. Why is that? I thought that a function making very explicit assumption about the type and the dimension of the input-array can be more competitive here. Of course, I also understand that numpy is incredible clever, but chances are that I am doing something stupid here...

Note that the point of this exercise is to not to rewrite a faster sin function but rather to create some cython wrappers for some of our internal tools but that's another issue for later...

Comment: Isn't there still boundschecking and such going on in your Cython code? In the [documentation example](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#numpy-tutorial), they turn it off at some point.

Comment: Yes, I have included that now. Only very minor improvements. Still almost factor 3...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466950/why-is-my-python-numpy-example-faster-than-pure-c-implementation

Comment: `numpy.zeros` is a terrible way to allocate memory. At least use `numpy.empty`.

Comment: @tschm `NumPy`'s sine function is probably vectorized, where only one function call is made for the whole array, while in your Cython routine a function call is needed for each array element...

Comment: @Veedrac, funny enough empty seems to slow down my version a bit... At least I didn't see any improvements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of variants and the performance on my machine (which may vary) using the cython magic in ipython:

```
%%cython --compile-args=-O3 -a

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

from libc.math cimport sin

def sin_array(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
    cdef int n = len(arr)
    cdef np.ndarray h = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(n):
        h[i] = sin(arr[i])
    return h

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sin_array1(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
    cdef int n = arr.shape[0]
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] h = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        h[i] = sin(arr[i])
    return h


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sin_array2(np.float64_t[:] arr):
    cdef int n = arr.shape[0]
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] h = np.empty(n, np.float64)
    cdef np.float64_t[::1] _h = h
    for i in range(n):
        _h[i] = sin(arr[i])
    return h
```

And for kicks, I threw in a Numba jitted method:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit
def sin_numba(x):
    n = x.shape[0]
    h = np.empty(n, np.float64)
    for k in range(n):
        h[k] = np.sin(x[k])

    return h
```

And the timings:

```
In [25]:

x = np.random.randn(1000)

%timeit np.sin(x)
%timeit sin_array(x)
%timeit sin_array1(x)
%timeit sin_array2(x)
%timeit sin_numba(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.4 µs per loop
```

The numpy built-in is still the fastest (but just by a little bit), and the numba performance is pretty good considering the simplicity of not specifying any type info.

*Update*:

It's also always good to take a look at a variety of array sizes. Here are the timings for an array of 10000 elements:

```
In [26]:

x = np.random.randn(10000)

%timeit np.sin(x)
%timeit sin_array(x)
%timeit sin_array1(x)
%timeit sin_array2(x)
%timeit sin_numba(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 267 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 783 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 267 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 268 µs per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop
```

Here you can see almost identical timings between the optimized versions of the original method and the `np.sin` call, pointing to some overhead in the initialization of the data structures in cython or the return. Numba fares slightly worse under these conditions.

Comment: What's the idea behind cdef np.float64_t[::1] _h = h?

Comment: It's a cython typed memoryview, and the `[::1]` tells cython that the memory is c-contiguous (which is guaranteed when you created `h`, but not necessarily for the input `arr`). That variant uses a trick that allows you to create the memory as a ndarray, then operate on it through the typed memoryview and then return the data as an ndarray (as opposed to calling `np.asarray` on the memoryview at the end, which is slower).

Comment: I'll also add that I didn't rigorously test what effect all of the optimizations had on the timing, but I would definitely check if compiling with `-O2` or `-O3` has an effect, and certainly as mentioned by @Bhante, giving cython info about `h` is likely key. And I second the recommendation of the `-a` flag to look at the annotated source.

Comment: Yes, my experiments confirm that the info about h is absolutely crucial for cython as mentioned by Bhante and done in your experiments @JoshAdel

Answer (score 8):

Cython's annotation feature, `cython -a filename.pyx` is your friend. It generates a html file which you can load in a browser and it highlights lines of code which are not well optimized. You can click on a line to see the generated c code.

In this case the problem appears to be that `h` is not properly typed. If you simply type an array as `ndarray` you're telling Cython that it's an array, but you're not giving cython enough information to tell it how to index it efficiently, you *must* give the type and shape information. You have done this correctly in the function declaration.

I imagine that once this has been fixed the performance will be comparable, but if it isn't annotate will tell you what's wrong. If cython is still slower then numpy probably uses a faster sin function than the standard c one (you can get much faster sin approximations, try googling it if interested).

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I am now only 20% slower than numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd update this using Python 3.6.1 and Cython 0.25.2.  As suggested by @blake-walsh **I correctly typed all variables** and used the -a option to **check that the code was translated to C** with no extra tests. I also used the newer typed memoryview approach to passing arrays to functions.

The result is that Cython, compiling Python to C and using C libraries for math functions is 45% faster than the Numpy solution.  Why?  Probably because Numpy has a number of checks and generalizations that I didn't add to the Cython version.  I've done a number of Cython vs C tests recently and, if you can use code that can be translated to C the difference isn't significant.  Cython really is fast.

The code is:

```
%%cython -c=-O3 -c=-march=native
import cython
cimport cython
from libc.math cimport sin

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef double [:] cy_sin(double [:] arr):
    cdef unsigned int i, n = arr.shape[0]
    for i in range(n):
        arr[i] = sin(arr[i])
    return arr

import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(1000)
%timeit np.sin(x)
%timeit cy_sin(x)
```

and the results were:

```
15.6 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
10.7 µs ± 58.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

**Edit:**
I added parallel processing by changing the code to:

```
%%cython --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp --force -c=-O3 -c=-march=native
import cython
cimport cython
cimport openmp
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
from libc.math cimport sin

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef double [:] cy_sin(double [:] arr):
    cdef int i, n = arr.shape[0]
    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
#     for i in range(n):
        arr[i] = sin(arr[i])
    return arr
```

On this small array, it approximately doubled speed (i5-3470 3.2GHz x4 processor) to complete in `5.75 µs`.  On larger 1M+ sized arrays it quadrupled speed.